# Left join on not null

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

How can I do a left join on `null` in Eloquent query builder?

I have 2 models: `Customer` (`customers` table) and `Appointment` (`appointments` table). A customer can have 0 or more appointments. Both customers and appointments can be soft deleted.

I would like to replicate this query in Query Builder:

*Query 1*:

```
SELECT max(a.date) AS max_date, c.* FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN appointments AS a ON a.customer_id = c.id AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE c.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I know that this:

```
Customer::selectRaw('max(appointments.date) as max_date, customers.*')
        ->leftJoin('appointments', 'appointments.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->where('appointments.deleted_at')
        ->groupBy('customers.id');
```

Results in this:

*Query 2*:

```
SELECT max(a.date) AS max_date, c.* FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN appointments AS a ON a.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id;
```

But there is a slight difference between *Query 1* and *Query 2*:

*Query 1* includes customers with all of their appointments soft deleted (and this is what I want). *Query 2* doesn't.

Is there a way do it in Eloquent, without resorting to subqueries? The output of this query goes to the 'index' view with 100 (or more) records *per page*, so I don't want to slow it down unnecessarily. I also want the user to be able to *sort* the results by max date.

Is my only reasonable option a plain 'raw sql query'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leftJoin()` accepts a closure:

```php
Customer::selectRaw('max(appointments.date) as max_date, customers.*')
    ->leftJoin('appointments', function($join) {
        $join->on('appointments.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
            ->where('appointments.deleted_at');
    })
    ->groupBy('customers.id');
```